# Problema con resample en python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

introducir el código aquíBuenas, como va?
Tengo un data set que va desde la fecha 29/12/21 al 10/2/22, dicho data set esta compuesto de la siguiente forma:

```
Time | Value Y | Time 2 | Value_horno | Time 3 | Value chimenea |
29/12/2021 0:00:44  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:00:44 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:00:44 | 1776
29/12/2021 0:00:45  | 1300 | 29/12/2021 0:00:45 | 1466 | 29/12/2021 0:00:45 | 1888
29/12/2021 0:00:46  | 1355 | 29/12/2021 0:00:46 | 1455 | 29/12/2021 0:00:46 | 1777
29/12/2021 0:00:47  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:00:47 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:00:47 | 1556
29/12/2021 0:00:48  | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:00:48 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:00:48 | 1555

2/2/2022 0:00:48    | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:00:48 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:00:48 | 1555
```

Lo primero que hago es pasar las variables Time a tipo de dato fecha, ya que es reconocida como
objecto. Luego utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
df.set_index("Time", inplace= True)
df_mean3 = df.resample("H").mean()
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es:

```
Time | Value Y | Time 2 | Value_horno | Time 3 | Value chimenea |
29/12/2021 0:00:00  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:00:00 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:00:00 | 1776
29/12/2021 0:01:00  | 1300 | 29/12/2021 0:01:00 | 1466 | 29/12/2021 0:01:00 | 1888
29/12/2021 0:02:00  | 1355 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1455 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1777
29/12/2021 0:03:00  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:03:00 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:03:00 | 1556
29/12/2021 0:04:00  | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:04:00 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:04:00 | 1555

11/2/2022 0:02:00   | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1555

11/3/2022 0:01:00   | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1555
```

Al hacer un `insa().sum()` me aparecen todas nands,

```
Time 300
Value y 300
Time 2 300
Value_horno 300
Time 3 300
Value chimenea 300
```

y no me respeta la frecuencia de los datos y cuando termina el data set, ya que lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente:

```
Time | Value Y | Time 2 | Value_horno | Time 3 | Value chimenea |
29/12/2021 0:00:00  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:00:00 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:00:00 | 1776
29/12/2021 0:01:00  | 1300 | 29/12/2021 0:01:00 | 1466 | 29/12/2021 0:01:00 | 1888
29/12/2021 0:02:00  | 1355 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1455 | 29/12/2021 0:02:00 | 1777
29/12/2021 0:03:00  | 1333 | 29/12/2021 0:03:00 | 1444 | 29/12/2021 0:03:00 | 1556
29/12/2021 0:04:00  | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:04:00 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:04:00 | 1555

10/2/2022 0:23:00   | 1334 | 29/12/2021 0:23:00 | 1445 | 29/12/2021 0:23:00 | 1555
```

y con isna.sum:

```
Time 0
Value y 0
Time 2 0
Value_horno 0
Time 3 0
Value chimenea 0
```

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ahi lo he arreglado, para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Aún no tiene un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable. Esto es importante ya que en este sitio todos somos voluntarios y para resolver los problemas con mayor eficacia es mejor copiar y pegar el código para reproducir el problema, por favor visita y lee el URL del comentario anterior